# Visually displaying items in an inventory (game wise)

Tags: java, image

I have an arraylist stored inside a Character class, I'm looking for ideas on how to visually display them in an inventory, an item for example may be 2x3 grids in size (64x96 pixels), while having it draggable (from inventory to equipment)

Comment: so far I tried having an array of ints, 1's(occupied) and 0's(empty). if an item is 2x3, a property inside is read, then if array[0] is equal to 0, its changed to 1 ect
then that info is read and the image is drawn starting from the nearest empty grid, say if array[0] is empty, it draws it at 0,0. (0 * 32), if array[1] is the next empty grid, its drawn at 32,0. (1 * 32) since each grid is 32x32

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach. Are you having a specific problem with it?